# irregular security error loading data with HTTP request flex 3.2 application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, httprequest

I have an application that worked for a client for 2 years now. All of a sudden it stopped working
and I traced it to a 'security error' that I get when attempting to get data from a php script that reads data from a mysql DB. It seems that data (a tab in a textfield) triggers that event, but it is irregular over various clients. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The script is OK, getting the data from a regular HTTP request in the browser works fine. Is there anyone who recognizes this behaviour ? I'm at a loss. The error is this:

Could not load any date from server ![FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"] messageId="6D8CAADA-D95F-F30D-0C2A-5AC1F3061A23" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]

and the script I read is here:

http://www.arti.nl/flyer/services/exhibitions.php

the application that uses it is the 'flyer' application you can trigger by clicking the red triangle in the agenda on this site:

www.arti.nl.

Thanks a lot !

Jonathan

Comment: What version of Flash Player you experiencing the issue in?  Can you use a packet sniffer to see the request / response?  Are the SWF and your service on the same domain? If not, is there a cross domain file in place?

Comment: we can prevent the error now by making  the request go out to the relative URI rather than the global URI (ie /flyer/services/exhibitions.php rather than http://www.arti.nl/flyer/services/exhibitions.php), but it still beats me why this should happen, it seems unrelated to the player version. The SWF and service are in the same domain.

Comment: That makes me think that the domain you're accessing is different from the domain your SWF is served from.  You should post a formal answer to your own question.

Comment: I would, but the question what causes the problem is not really answered, so it doesn't really help anyone if I answer that I made the URI's relative..